# How to use integers in string array?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Good day, how can I make this work like this?

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent int1 = getIntent();
    final String category = int1.getStringExtra("category");
    final int level = int1.getIntExtra("level", 0);

    if (level == 0) {final String[] a = new String[]{"heart", "spade"};
    if (level == 1) {final String[] a = new String[]{"black", "blue"};
```

I want to use `a` in my Edit text with different value in every `level` but `a` isnt working.

```
     if (answer1.getText().toString().contains(a))
```

If I remove `if (level == 0)` , the value of `level` goes to `"heart", "spade"`. I cannot use this because I am using `.contains` in two or more words.

I already tried `final String[] stringvar = new String[]{Arrays.toString(a), Arrays.toString(b)};` + `.contains(stringvar[level])` but it's no good.

So what I need is `a` contains different value in every `level`.
or for every string array that only 1 value.
for example:

`final String[] a = new String[]{"asd ", "qwe"} = 0`

`final String[] b = new String[]{"dsa ", "dsa} = 1`

Thank you. Please tell me if my question is hard to understand.

Comment: I'm honestly still unclear about what you want to achieve. From what I understand: You have an `int level` depending on which you want to populate `String a[]`? Also, if you remove the `if (level == 0)`, the value of `level` will NOT be equal to `"heart", "spade"` because they're not the same types, and you're also not declaring the value of `level`.

Comment: `a` is local to your `if`, it does not exist as soon as you leave the block. read about variable scope and try again.

Comment: if a is already there and it is an int you can convert it to String by using `Integer.toString(a)`

Comment: Mr. @Sidak, im not sure with the code ```level ==0``` . to be precise to what i want, this app is quiz app that need to type to answer (and the exact answer is sentence) and I want to correct their answer even though they didnt get the exact sentence but they get the important word. So what i use is ```.contains``` . 
 . But I need to input hundreds of 2 or more words and using stringarray will solve it. (one string array per answer). and my problem is how can I distrubute many string array to connect it to my integers. like ```level = 0``` = StringArray1 and ```level = 1``` = StringArray2.

Comment: Mr @eduyayo. where should I put that? inside on create or edit text? sorry Im a newbie

Comment: `"a string value with 1 inside".contains(Integer.toString(1))` returns `true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from what I understand, You want an Array of Strings for each corresponding level. I recommend you check out the `Map` datatype. You create a `Map<Integer, String[]>` that stores your level number and array of words you want to check the answer for.

A sample is:

```
Map<Integer,String[]> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, {"asd ", "qwe"}); // Level 1
map.put(2, {"dsa", "dsa"}); // Level 2
```

You can then use `map.get(n)` to get the String array for the nth level etc. in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the help but i cant make it work. I found simple solution though. Please take a look.

```String[][] coupleArray = new String[][]{ { "asd", "ads" }, { "Peter", "Abigail" };``` 

```edittext.getText().toString().contains(coupleArray[level][level])```

but I cant put ```level``` on the 2nd bracket because i want to get all the values of that.
what should i put on the 2nd bracket of coupleArray?

Comment: you can make a loop and set the second bracket value as the variable. It would be something like, `for(int i = 0; i < coupleArray[level].length; i++){ edittext...contains(coupleArray[level][i]);}`

Comment: Good day Mr. Sidak, i thought I get what i want but I discovered that it only gets the last word "ads" and not both. sorry for bothering :)

Comment: i tried to change ```for(int i = 0; i < coupleArray[level].length; i++)``` to ```for(int i = 0; i < coupleArray[i].length; i++)``` but its the same

Comment: That shouldn't be happening John, I ran the code on my side and it works perfectly fine. Here is what I ran: `int level = 0;
    String[][] coupleArray = new String[][]{ { "asd", "ads" }, { "Peter", "Abigail" }};
    for(int i = 0; i < coupleArray[level].length; i ++){
        System.out.println(coupleArray[0][i]);
    }`

Comment: it copy/paste ur code and tried it to my edittext.contains but no luck. 
maybe that doesnt work on contains. 

How about arraylist ? or something like create many different string[] and set each string[] to ```level``` . is that even possible?

Comment: I just tried running it with String.contains, and it worked for me... What error are you getting, exactly? and are you fetching the value from the EditText correctly?

Comment: i think because of this  ```final int finalI = i;``` . 

```if (answer1.getText().toString().contains(coupleArray[level][finalI]))```

if I put ```i``` int the 2nd bracket. there is an error that says Variable 'i' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final. If i alt+shift+enter. ```final int finalI = i;``` .  appears

Comment: there is no error actually, they didnt get all the value, if i type "asd ads" its correct, if i type "ads", it is still correct. the 2 word must should appear in edit text to make it correct

Comment: ```String[] a = new String[] {"ads", "asd"}``` this code works. ```.contains(a)```

Something pop-up in my mind.

```String[] a = new String[] {"ads", "asd"};```
```String[] b = new String[] {"ads", "asd"};```

It is possible to set a = 0 and b = 1 and connect this on ```level``` . 

This is my last problem, after this i can now finish my project hahaha

Comment: Why exactly are you putting a final int? If you just loop over the array like I mentioned in the first comment, using `i`, it will work just fine. Also, Do you want all the words in the array to be in the string? or any 1 of all the words

Comment: i dont know why, because if i Didnt, there is red underline in ```i``` . 

as u can see we use String [][] . so if i am in the activity that have level = 0 , i need to get both "ads" and "asd" . if level = 1 , the next 2 words.

Comment: That doesn't matter. the variable `level` decides which set of words to select, and `i` decides which word in the set to select

Comment: oh so ```i``` cant get 2 words at the same time. 

```String[] a = new String[] {"ads", "asd"}``` But this code works. if i use edittext.contains(a). the edit text must contain "a ds" and "asd" in order to make it correct. but why 2d string dontwork T_T

Comment: Oh, if you want to compare the whole array, then just do `String.contains(coupleArray[level])`. This will return the Array of Strings to compare your string with